# Окончание местоимения "я"

Tags: морфология, морфемика, морфемный-разбор, местоимения

У местоимения "я" нулевое окончание?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У местоимения *я* нет никакого окончания, потому что оно не изменяется -- при склонении используются падежные формы с другим корнем (меня, мой и т. д.).

Такое явление называется супплетивным словоизменением.